# ./ 1.cpp commands gives error: bash: ./: Is a directory

Tags: g++

After `vi 1.cpp`
I write my C++ Program.

```
g++ 1.cpp -o 1.out
```

works fine.
But

```
./ 1.out
```

gives Error: bash: **./: Is a directory**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `./1.out`, no space between `./` and `1.out`.